# Email Etiquette: when is it polite to stop talking?

Tags: email

I'm often in situations where I'll send an email like this one:

> Hi, thing X will be getting done next week

I'll get a response,

> OK, I'm glad to see it's going well.

Odd question: I always feel that it is polite to say something like "thanks" to that, but it's also a waste of an email and potentially someone's time.  However, I feel like I'm being rude by not acknowledging a compliment.  I'm over thinking it, but is there a procedure I can follow in situations like this?

Comment: Also: [Response's 'respectfulness'/etiquette for an email that does not ask for a reply](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21223)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless they replied back with a question, I don't think you should.

Maybe add in a text that you'll send another email once its been released:

> Hi, thing X will be done next week. Once it is ready for your review, I will send a follow up email.

That way you're saying you won't reply back.